# How to combine @Entity and @XmlRootElement in one class

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jpa, jaxb

I am facing a situation that a REST service takes XML request and need to store the data in the request into database. The request XML basically gives values of a class that needs to be persisted.

For example, suppose I need to persist a class as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

The request XML may look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PersonInputs>
    <Input type="String" name="firstName">Foo</Input>
    <Input type="String" name="lastName">Bar</Input>
</PersonInputs>
```

Is it possible that I can use JAXB annotations to create a `Person` object and bind data from the request XML in a simple way? I am not familiar with JAXB for the moment, so I hope I can get some informed suggestions. Nevertheless, any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have the exact format of the xml?

Comment: @DebojitSaikia: If you are referring to a XSD, we don't have one. We probably should, but we have never gotten to it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution with additional class `Input`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Input 
{
   @XmlAttribute
   private String type;
   @XmlAttribute
   private String name;
   @XmlValue
   private String value;

   public Input() {}

   public Input(String type, String name, String value) 
   {
      this.type = type;
      this.name = name;
      this.value = value;
   }
}
```

and additional getters in entity
**Variant 1**

```
@XmlRootElement(name= "PersonInputs")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Person
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id; 

    private String firstName = "foo";

    private String lastName = "bar";

    // getters/setters

    @XmlElement(name= "Input")
    Input getFirstNameXML()
    {
       return new Input(String.class.getSimpleName(), "firstName", firstName);
    }

    @XmlElement(name= "Input")
    Input getLastNameXML()
    {
       return new Input(String.class.getSimpleName(), "lastName", lastName);
    }
}
```

**Variant 2**

```
@XmlRootElement(name= "PersonInputs")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Person
{
    private Long id; 

    private String firstName = "foo";

    private String lastName = "bar";

    // getters/setters

    @XmlElement(name = "Input")
    List<Input> getList() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException
    {
       return getInputs(this, "firstName", "lastName"); // fields names
    }
}
```

Util method `getInputs`

```
static List<Input> getInputs(Object thisObj, String ... fields) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException
{
   final List<Input> retVal = new ArrayList<Input>();
   for (String field : fields)
   {
      Field f = thisObj.getClass().getDeclaredField(field);
      f.setAccessible(true);
      retVal.add(new Input(f.getType().getSimpleName(), field, (String )f.get(thisObj)));
   }
   return retVal;   
}
```